# Looking for a VBScript to move files older than 3 years to a new folder while keeping the folder structure

Tags: vbscript

I am looking to move files from my file server to a tape drive to save space. I need a script that will allow me to move all the files that were accessed 3 years ago or later while still keeping their folder structure.

E.g. d:\share\it\test.txt -> d:\archive\share\it\test.txt, assuming the test.txt file hasn't been accessed in 3 years

I will then run a tape backup over this folder.

I have some scripts that I have been using. The most effective one I have used is this one, but tt doesn't recreate the file structure in the test folder :

```
Dim objFSO, ofolder, objStream, strSafeDate, strSafeTime, strDateTime, strLogFileName

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strSafeDate = DatePart("yyyy",Date) & Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2) & Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date), 2)
strSafeTime = Right("0" & Hour(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Minute(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Second(Now), 2)

Set strDateTime equal to a string representation of the current date and time, for use as part of a valid Windows filename

strDateTime = strSafeDate & "-" & strSafeTime

'Assemble the path and filename
strLogFileName ="Move File " & strDateTime & ".txt"
set outfile = fso.createtextfile(strLogFileName,true)
SPath = "I:\Tech Docs"
Sdest = "I:\Test\"

ShowSubfolders FSO.GetFolder(spath)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        CheckFolder(subfolder)
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
End Sub

'CheckFolder(objFSO.getFolder(SPath))

Sub CheckFolder(objCurrentFolder)
    Dim strTempL, strTempR, strSearchL, strSearchR, objNewFolder, objFile
    Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
    currDate = Date
    dtmDate = DateAdd("d",-0,Now)
    strTargetDate = ConvDate(dtmDate)
    For Each objFile In objCurrentFolder.Files
        FileName = objFile
        'WScript.Echo FileName
        'strDate = ConvDate(objFile.DateCreated)
        strDate = ConvDate(objFile.DateLastAccessed)
        If strDate < strTargetDate Then
            objFSO.MoveFile FileName, Sdest
            outfile.writeline Filename
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function ConvDate (sDate) 'Converts MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS to string YYYYMMDD
    strModifyDay = day(sDate)
    If len(strModifyDay) < 2 Then
        strModifyDay = "0" & strModifyDay
    End If
    strModifyMonth = Month(sDate)
    If len(strModifyMonth) < 2 Then
        strModifyMonth = "0" & strModifyMonth
    End If
    strModifyYear = Year(sDate)
    ConvDate = strModifyYear & strModifyMonth & strModifyDay
End Function
    `
```

Comment: What are you asking?  If you have a script and it's effective... what exactly is the issue?

Comment: This script is as close as i got. It doesn't recreate the file structure in the test folder. I guess i should have said "this script is as close as i got".

Comment: Basically i need to figure out how to get the script to recreate the file path in the test folder, then move the file out of its original destination and into that new path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim objFSO, ofolder, objStream, strSafeDate, strSafeTime, strDateTime, strLogFileName

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strSafeDate = DatePart("yyyy",Date) & Right("0" & DatePart("m",Date), 2) & Right("0" & DatePart("d",Date), 2)
strSafeTime = Right("0" & Hour(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Minute(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Second(Now), 2)

Set strDateTime equal to a string representation of the current date and time, for use as part of a valid Windows filename

strDateTime = strSafeDate & "-" & strSafeTime

'Assemble the path and filename
strLogFileName ="Move File " & strDateTime & ".txt"
set outfile = fso.createtextfile(strLogFileName,true)
SPath = "I:\Tech Docs\"
Sdest = "I:\Test\"

ShowSubfolders FSO.GetFolder(spath)

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    CheckFolder Folder
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
End Sub

'CheckFolder(objFSO.getFolder(SPath))

Sub CheckFolder(objCurrentFolder)
    Dim strTempL, strTempR, strSearchL, strSearchR, objNewFolder, objFile
    Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE
    currDate = Date
    dtmDate = DateAdd("d",-0,Now)
    strTargetDate = ConvDate(dtmDate)
    For Each objFile In objCurrentFolder.Files

        'Since we want to preserve the path, we've got to reconstruct it
        sAbsPath = objFile.Path
        'Swap source and destination in the path, and strip the file name
        'from the path.
        sNewPath = Replace(Replace(sAbsPath,sPath,Sdest),"\" & objFile.Name,"")
        'Here we reconstruct the path if it doesn't exist in the
        'destination with our new Sub "MakeDir"
        MakeDir sNewPath

        FileName = objFile
        'WScript.Echo FileName
        'strDate = ConvDate(objFile.DateCreated)
        strDate = ConvDate(objFile.DateLastAccessed)
        If strDate =< strTargetDate Then
            'Finally we copy the file to the sNewPath
            objFSO.MoveFile FileName, sNewPath & "\"
            outfile.writeline Filename
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub MakeDir(strPath)
    On Error Resume Next
        strParentPath = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(strPath)

        If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strParentPath) Then MakeDir strParentPath
        If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strPath) Then objFSO.CreateFolder strPath
    On Error Goto 0 
End Sub

Function ConvDate (sDate) 'Converts MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS to string YYYYMMDD
    strModifyDay = day(sDate)
    If len(strModifyDay) < 2 Then
        strModifyDay = "0" & strModifyDay
    End If
    strModifyMonth = Month(sDate)
    If len(strModifyMonth) < 2 Then
        strModifyMonth = "0" & strModifyMonth
    End If
    strModifyYear = Year(sDate)
    ConvDate = strModifyYear & strModifyMonth & strModifyDay
End Function
```

Comment: Use your words. What are you asking?

Comment: In words: Don't post air code. There is no .GetAbsolutePathName method of the File object.

Comment: My mistake, I was using the FSO method. http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/14060, I updated the script.

Comment: Ok i can see the folders have been recreated. The only problem is that now its not moving the files to the folders. its creating a folder called the document name. So if there is a document called test.doc, after the script is run. it then makes a folder called test.doc rather than moving the test.doc file to the folder

Comment: I thought it might do that. Try it again I updated the "sNewPath" line.

Comment: @NathanRice - air code again. If you replace sPath in File.Path by sDest you make a dir from the full file spec.

Comment: Not sure I'd call this air code, it's untested because I don't have an environment to test in, but it's completely custom to your specs. I'd be a little more grateful in your tone if I were you.

Comment: Ok this time it copied the folders, did not create folder names for the files inside those folders like it did before. it did not copy the files though. Also i am getting an error. Line 55 Char 13 with an error called "File already exists." I want to thank you for your help on this. It means a lot to me.

Comment: I added a `& "\"` to the end of line 55. That should fix it.

Comment: OK final question. This script isnt moving all of the files like i expected it to. I have the days set to 0 which i assumed would move ALL files to the new destination. Some of the folders are not getting moved and the root path (in this case I:\Tech Docs\ has some files inside of it. They are not being moved as well. Is this something to be worried about or should i test another folder to check?

Comment: The date issue is because this line `If strDate < strTargetDate Then` should be `If strDate =< strTargetDate Then`.

Comment: without a doubt completely thrilled about this. I want to thank you so much for your help. It means a lot to know there are people out there willing to help out those in need. thanks again